Selenium in python Unable to locate element error 404
I am trying to use selenium in python to click the load more button to show all the reviews in a specific webpage, however, I am encountering some issues when finding the button element in selenium which always return an ** Error: 404 - No Such Element: Unable to locate element**
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)


url = 'https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/allegra-adult-24hr-tablet-180-mg,-allergy-relief/ID=300409806-product'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    try:
        # loadMoreBtn1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , 'button.bv-rnr__sc-16j1lpy-3 bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-1.jSgrbb.gSrzYA')
        # loadMoreBtn2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="bv-rnr__sc-16j1lpy-3 bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-1 jSgrbb gSrzYA"]')
        loadMoreBtn3 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'bv-rnr__sc-16j1lpy-3 bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-1 jSgrbb gSrzYA')
        loadMoreBtn3.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break

I already tried finding the element by css, xpath and class name with no luck in making it work.
I checked the webpage and it seems the class name is fix as well
<div class="bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-0 gcGJRh">
  <button aria-label="Load More , This action will load more reviews on screen" class="bv-rnr__sc-16j1lpy-3 bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-1 jSgrbb gSrzYA">Load More</button>
</div>

I also tried the CTRL+F to test the css and xpath in the page source and it returns zero match as well.


The class attribute in the DOM is a space-separated list of classes. For By.CLASS_NAME you can provide only one of these.

Does this answer your question? Find by Class name command is not working

Hi @SiKing, thank you for your response, I already tested the By.CSS_SELECTOR option previously (I just commented out it (loadMoreBtn1). I also tried this just to be sure driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bv-rnr__sc-16j1lpy-3 bv-rnr__sc-17t5kn5-1.jSgrbb.gSrzYA') and still returned error 404

I'd simplify the code and use their Ajax API to get more reviews:
import requests

url = "https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json"

params = {
    "resource": "reviews",
    "action": "REVIEWS_N_STATS",
    "filter": [
        "productid:eq:300409806",   # <--- change this to product ID
        "contentlocale:eq:en,en_AU,en_CA,en_GB,en_US,en_US",
        "isratingsonly:eq:false",
    ],
    "filter_reviews": "contentlocale:eq:en,en_AU,en_CA,en_GB,en_US,en_US",
    "include": "authors,products,comments",
    "filteredstats": "reviews",
    "Stats": "Reviews",
    "limit": "30",
    "offset": "8",
    "limit_comments": "3",
    "sort": "submissiontime:desc",
    "passkey": "tpcm2y0z48bicyt0z3et5n2xf",
    "apiversion": "5.5",
    "displaycode": "2001-en_us",
}

for page in range(3):  # <-- change this for required number of pages
    params["offset"] = 30 * page

    data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    for r in data["Results"]:
        print(r["UserNickname"], " -> ", r["ReviewText"])
        print()

Prints:

...

AllergyMan2  ->  [This review was collected as part of a promotion.] This was the first time I used Allegra and I'm thoroughly impressed with this product. I've used other allergy pills in the past and this one takes the cake, it's fast acting for all your allergy needs. I recommend if your like me and you have used them all and just want one that works go get some Allegra 24 hour and you'll be in great hands.

pinkdiemond1  ->  [This review was collected as part of a promotion.] I got the chance to try Allegra 24Hr 60ct Tablets thru Home Tester.  The pills were easy to swallow and fast acting.  I did not get sleep after a few hours of ingestion.  Yes I would recommend Allegra 24Hr 60ct Tablets to my friends and family.

Rachael7  ->  [This review was collected as part of a promotion.] I have seasonal allergies and my first pick is always Allegra. I love that it works within an hour of using and I feel great all day. A plus that it’s non drowsy. The only suggestion I’d like to make is: have the pill me smaller. Other than that, it’s great to take for those annoying allergy symptoms.

...


Hi @Andrej Kesely, thank you for this solution. Although, the solution is not relevant to the issue why i cannot find the elements using selenium, I can confirm its working, I can get the reviews to the website that im using. Just one concern though, is the passkey that you used a public key? or do i need to create my own key? I just need to get some reviews of some products hope its ok if i use the passkey for a short period of time :)

@Kristkun I'm not sure about the passkey, it's probably to identify from where this api call comes from. You can open Web Developer Tools and observe the parameters in your browser (if the passkey is different then change it).
